# Does Georgia (USA) tax unemployment income, dividends, and capital gains that was earned during months where the taxpayer was in a different state?

Tags: united-states, taxes, georgia

I'm doing my 2020 taxes in tax software on which I purchased the state return for CA and GA. I moved to CA from GA in mid-Jan 2020. During the year of 2020, I earned employment income, unemployment income, dividends, and capital gains - all while being a resident in CA.

The tax software automatically removed employment income from my GA state return, but includes the other types of income mentioned above. Is this correct (i.e., does GA tax unemployment income, dividends, and capital gains that was earned during months where the taxpayer was in a different state)?

Comment: What is the exact date you established tax residency in Georgia?

Comment: Many years ago, but I if you meant to ask when I came from Georgia to California: January 19, 2020.

Comment: When you moved did you establish tax residency in the new state: get a drivers license, register to vote, register your car? That may be the key date.

Comment: I never registered to vote in CA and never got my driver's license in CA, but registered my car there shortly after moving there (a few days after January 19, 2020).

Comment: Careful. Georgia might claim that you are still a resident of Georgia, who temporarily did some work in California. They might want you to pay taxes on the income.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just completed my taxes and it turns out the software silently re-adjustes the amount from state A if one enters the earnings from state B because it knows the total yearly/federal amounts. The software also mentions that one is only taxed for the earnings received while being a resident in each state separately. So, one is not double-taxed, in this case at least.